# Getting 404 Not Found on NGINX when uploading a file via Django Admin

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm working on an NGINX + Gunicorn + PostgreSQL + Django + Docker project but I'm having problems when uploading files via the Django admin.

When I upload the server receives it and creates the proper database entries for it (User who made it, date, filename, etc.) This content shows flawlessly but when I try to access this file I keep getting a `404 Not Found` message.

If I manually access the Gunicorn Docker container volume and do a `find / -name "Filename.pdf"` it does find the file inside `/opt/services/media/files/2018-07-29/Filename.pdf` so it looks like the file is being uploaded, then why am I unable to access it?

This is my **NGINX** config:

```
# Upstream server, which is our Gunicorn application.
upstream project_server {
    server webapp:8000;
}

# Main server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 5M;

    location /static {
        alias /opt/services/webapp/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /opt/services/webapp/media;
    }

    location / {
        # Everything is passed to Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://project_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

For **Gunicorn** I execute it with: `CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", "project", "project.wsgi:application"]` and the config:

```
name = 'project'
loglevel = 'info'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
workers = 2
```

My [**models.py**](https://models.py)

```
import os
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from utils.validators import validate_file_extension
from utils.generic import content_file_name
from users.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Users(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='published by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=140)
    file = models.FileField(_('file'), upload_to=content_file_name,
                            validators=[validate_file_extension])
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, editable=False, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('My users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ext = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)[1]
        if ext:
            self.type = ext
        try:
            model = Users.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if self.file != model.file:
                model.file.delete()
        except: pass
        return super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I serve my files correctly?

Static content such as CSS and images is working correclty.

Comment: I don't know if this helps...but your search finds the file at `/opt/services/media/files/2018-07-29/Filename.pdf` but your nginx config is serving media files from: `/opt/services/webapp/media`. These are not the same paths.

Comment: Thanks @Nizebulous, when I click on the filename url it redirects me to `http://localhost/media/files/2018-07-29/Folleto_uno.pdf`, so probably NGINX is looking for a file that is not stored where it is actually stored?
What would be the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Either change the nginx config so that it points to where django is uploading the files...or change the django config to match nginx....I find it interesting that your static files are found in the correct place...you might see that they are configured the same way.